# Select2 shrinks it's width after selecting a option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 jquery it works fine in chrome, opera and mozilla firefox.

But not in Internet Explorer, I am using the IE version 11

After selecting the option the select box shrinks to 0.95px

Following is the span created by select2 Initially

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" style="width:479px;" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1">some html</span>
```

After setting the width in the constructor as following

```
    $("body").find(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2( 
        {
            placeholder: "select one",
            allowClear: true,
            width: '100%',
       }
    );
```

The width is set to 100% as following

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" style="width: 100%;" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1">some html</span>
```

But after selecting a option from select box the box width shrinks to 0.95px as follows, this happens only in ie

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" style="width: 0.95px;" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="251">some html</span>
```

Comment: Did you try `css` important?

Comment: @Pedram I tried it, it shows 100% then changes back to .95px since it's changed using js

Comment: Maybe you saw this [Topic](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3278) before, but I think it's same as yours. Check it out again, Specially last post.

Comment: @ Pedram using this only I set the width to 100% in constructor